# Can't Delete file with File.Delete(path)

Tags: asp.net, file-io

I'm unable to delete file with this command ..

```
Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
```

Im getting the above error .. 
However Im able to download file with the very same path..

Additional Details: I've have File path saved in the DataBase..
and files are in the ~\Upload\ folder ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path like this "~\Upload\ folder" are virtual paths. You need to convert them to physical path to delete them.

If you are in web context then use the following code to get physical path and then delete them.

```
var physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/folder/file.html"); //to get the physical path

File.Delete(physicalPath);
```

Comment: thanks alot Sir.. i was able to download the file with the old path so i was trying to delete with the same path too .. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are escaping any backslashes/forward, and just generally check that your path is complete with no small errors.

Failing that make sure your program has the correct privileges to delete the file.

Sorry I can't be more specific but you have not shown your code.